# How can i create my own SharePoint hive Folder?

Tags: sharepoint, hive

Can we create our own virtual folder in 15 hive. so when we create any new web application. that folder need to be accessible across sites.

Like we have _layouts and _admin folders

Answer (score 0):

These virtual folders are called [Mapped Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231521.aspx). They can be created and populated via SharePoint solutions created in Visual Studio.

> You can add mapped folders to a project by using commands on the menu bar or the shortcut menu for the project. You can use the **Add SharePoint “Images” Mapped Folder** and **Add SharePoint “Layouts” folder** commands to add those mapped folders that are used most often. You can map any of the other available SharePoint folders to your project by using the **Add SharePoint Mapped Folder** command on the shortcut menu and then specifying the folders in the **Add SharePoint Mapped Folder** dialog box.
>
> -[*How to: Add and Remove Mapped Folders*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231521.aspx)

That Microsoft how-to article in the above link explains the process in greater detail, but here are the most relevant instructions:

> 7. In **Solution Explorer**, choose the project node, and then, on the menu bar, choose **Project**, **Add SharePoint Mapped Folder** to display the **Add SharePoint Mapped Folder** dialog box.
> 8. In the tree view of folders that are available for mapping, choose the **Resources** folder, and then choose the **OK** button.
>
>    A folder that's named **Resources** appears in your project. This folder can store items such as string resource files. Sub-folders can be useful for organizing the contents of a mapped folder, but they're not automatically created when you add a mapped folder by using the **Add SharePoint Mapped Folder** command. To add a sub-folder, choose the **Resources** folder, and then, on the menu bar, choose **Project**, **New Folder**.